# XS-6 columns on a Bootstrap 3 site stay stacked on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I'm working on this Bootstrap 3 site:

http://ghitulescu.de/beta/TRR/TuerenReuss/TuerenReuss/index.html

and I'd like to have the 21 small col-xs-6 columns lining up horizontally (two on each row) (the small previews right to "*Köhnlein Türen*") as long as the viewport is

- bigger than @screen-xs-min = 480px and
- smaller than @screen-xs-max = 767px

and have them stacked vertically only when the viewport becomes smaller than @screen-xs-min = 480px.

However they stay stacked even when the viewport is > 480 px so I have a real long site on a mobile device to scroll :-(

The HTML-code looks like this:

```
<main role="main">            
    <div class="page-contents container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"><!-- Galerie Weißlack -->
                <a href="https://www.koehnlein-tueren.de/showroom-innentueren0.0.html" target="_blank" title="Galerie Weißlack">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block schreinerinnung-logo" alt="Galerie Weißlack" src="img/kataloge/koehnlein/IT_Galerie_Weisslack.jpg">
                </a>
            </div><!-- /Galerie Weißlack -->

            (the above <div> 21 times!!!)

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

and the class "*schreinerinnung-logo*" handles only the top margin:

```
.schreinerinnung-logo {
    @media (min-width: @screen-xs-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

---

Trying to find the error I even replaced the a-tag with a simple paragraph (also 21 times), like this:

```
<main role="main">            
    <div class="page-contents container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            (the above <div> 21 times)

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

… with no effect: in viewports smaller than @screen-xs-max = 767px the columns stack on each other and don't line up horizontally. :-(

[image: a test-page with Lorem ipsum instead of <a>-tags]

One interesting fact: changing from col-xs-6 to col-xs-2 or col-xs-4 changes the width of the text in the paragraph, so it seems that the xs-information permeates but there is some sort of last rule that says that in xs everything should be stacked vertically even when there is plenty of horizontal space to line up a couple of elements side by side.

What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Regards,
Vlad

Comment: first you don't have any container

Comment: There is one, of course, for the main-section. The site behave responsive from lg over md through sm, only in xs and smaller then 480px I have this problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override a `clear:both` here:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.page-contents [class^=col] {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but searching for "*767px*" in all the less-files didn't find anything and putting the above code (with a pair of {} more) in _page-contents.less didn't solve the problem. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I even made a class with your media-query in it and assign it to the div with the row-class, but it didn't work either. :-(

Comment: Sorry, I understand now - I've made the change in the class page-contents and everything is fine! Thank you very much, Gabriella! :-)